# app widget not starting main activity after click on widget

Tags: android, android-activity, configuration, android-widget

I want to create an app widget with a confguration activity, the problem is when I add the widget to home the configuration activity is shown but when I click on button config the main activity does not start.... when I click on the Widget nothing happens. There are no errors in my Main activity. because if I start the app, it works without any errors...
I don't know what I m doing wrong :(. Thank you very much for your help...

here is the code:

```
public class WidgetConfiguration extends Activity{
final Context context = this;
EditText url;
EditText password;
int mAppWidgetId;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
    initializeAppWidget();
    showConfigDlg();
    final Context context = WidgetConfiguration.this;
    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
            R.layout.widget_layout);

}

private void initializeAppWidget(){ 
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        mAppWidgetId = extras.getInt(
                AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, 
                AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
    }
    if (mAppWidgetId == AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID) {
         finish();
    }
}

private void showConfigDlg(){
    setContentView(R.layout.widget_config);
    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.saveBtn)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.d("blablabla", "setting the onClick1");
            AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                    R.layout.widget_layout);
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(mAppWidgetId, views);
            Intent resultValue = new Intent();
            resultValue.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, mAppWidgetId);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, resultValue);
            finish();
        }
    });
}
}


public class WidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider
 {
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,  
          int[] appWidgetIds) {  
    final int N = appWidgetIds.length;
    Log.d("blablabla", "setting the onClick2");
    // Perform this loop procedure for each App Widget that belongs to this provider
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];
        Log.d("blablabla", "setting the onClick3");
        // Create an Intent to launch ExampleActivity
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

        // Get the layout for the App Widget and attach an on-click listener
        // to the button
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button, pendingIntent);


        // Tell the AppWidgetManager to perform an update on the current app widget
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
       }
    } 
 }
```